# xslt tansform Displaying time with the localtime zone

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My xml value is `<SaleDate>2017-12-28T13:30:08.1398094-05:00</SaleDate>`
my xsl

`<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(m:SaleHeader/m:SaleDate, 'MMM dd yyyy')"/> 
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="ms:format-time(m:SaleHeader/m:SaleDate, 'h:mm tt')"/>`

and in html I get the  value Dec 30 6:30 PM that's the UTC value
how do I get it should display the local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose in your case it is possible to use substring before formatting. Then it will provide the expected result.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(substring(m:SaleHeader/m:SaleDate, 1, 19), 'MMM dd yyyy')"/> 

<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-time(substring(m:SaleHeader/m:SaleDate, 1, 19), 'h:mm tt')"/>
```